# How to rename all files in a folder by excluding unwanted text?

Tags: java, file-rename

I'm a beginner in Java. I would like to remove this text "_signed_20240103121502" in the file.
I found many questions about rename file, but I cannot find the solution appropriate for me.

**Example files**

> 20230626_EdcPgw_0012041844_0001131023000001_ETAX_signed_20240103121502.pdf 20230626_EdcPgw_0531072999_0001131023000003_ETAX_signed_20240103121502.pdf 20230626_EdcPgw_4322053252_0001131023000005_ETAX_signed_20240103121503.pdf
> 20230626_EdcPgw_ETAX-PWD_signed_20240103121521.PWD

**After renaming it should be like this.**

> 20230626_EdcPgw_0012041844_0001131023000001_ETAX.pdf
> 20230626_EdcPgw_0531072999_0001131023000003_ETAX.pdf
> 20230626_EdcPgw_4322053252_0001131023000005_ETAX.pdf 
> 20230626_EdcPgw_ETAX-PWD.PWD

Comment: I personlly think that is not the right usecase for a java application. for this it is better to use bash or powershell depends on the OS you are working with

Comment: `rename -n 's/.*_(2024.*)/\1/' *` Drop the `-n` when you see it will do what you want with all files. `sudo apt install rename` if you don't have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.nio.file.Files` utility class contains all the methods you need for this.

1. Create a regex using the `Pattern` class.
2. Navigate to the folder and iterate over the files via `Files.walk(..)`
3. Filter the `Path` by finding a match with the pattern
4. Create the new path by replacing the found string
5. Use `Files.move(..)` to rename the old to the new path